# On the solvability group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, solvable-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups such that

1. $|G|=|H|$;
2. for every natural number $n$ the number of elements of order $n$ in $G$ and $H$ are equal;
3. $H$ is a solvable group.

Is $G$ solvable?

or

Is there any counterexample?

Condition $2$ requires two groups are the same order type.
If $G$ is a finite group and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $G(n):=\{x\in
G|x^{n}=1\}$. We say that the groups $G$ and $H$ are of the
same order type if $|G(n)|=|H(n)|$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

J. G. Thompson has a problem on the same order type group:

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups of the same order type such that $H$ is solvable. Is $G$ solvable?

Comment: You have changed the question, but it is still missing any context or motivation.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Motivation of the question added.

Comment: So you are just re-asking Thompson's question? I guess I should vote to reopen then!