# On 1987, J.G.Thompson's conjecture

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a Group. The set of element orders of $G$ and the set of numbers of the same
order elements in $G$ are denoted by $π_e(G)$ and $τ_e(G)$ (sometimes nse($G$)), respectively. Let $π(n)$ be the
set of prime divisors of $n$ and $π(G) = π(|G|)$ if $G$ is finite. In 1987, J.G.Thompson
posed a very interesting problem related to algebraic number fields as follows.

Problem: Let $T(G)=\lbrace (n,s_n)|n∈π_e(G) , s_n ∈ τ_e(G)\rbrace$, where $s_n$ is the number
of elements with order $n$. Suppose that $T(G)=T(H)$. If $G$ is a finite solvable Group,
is it true that H is also necessarily solvable?
So far, no one can solve this problem completely even give a counterexample. In
1986, someone studied the case of the simple Group $A5$, and he
proved an interesting result using only $π_e(G)$, that is, a finite Group $G$ is isomorphic
to $A5$ if and only if $π_e(G)$ = {1, 2, 3, 5}. Afterward, many simple Groups are
discovered by the characterization using only the set of element orders. Comparing
the sizes of elements of same order but disregarding the actual orders of elements in
$T(G)$ of the Thompson Problem, in other words, it remains only $τ_e(G)$, whether can
it characterize finite simple Groups? Up to now, There are some papers that have characterized a Group $G$ only in terms of the set $τ_e(G)$ and there are some papers that have characterized $G$ by $τ_e(G)$ and some more conditions. Has the Thompson Problem been solved completely so far?

Comment: " the set of numbers of the same order elements in $G$": I have no idea what you mean by this.

Comment: This same question was asked recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174888). As far as I know the Thompson conjecture remains unresolved.